# Convert Apple Push Certificate from .pem to .p12 (PKCS12)

Tags: certificate, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to convert an Apple Push Certificate (received in .pem format from https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/) to PKCS12 on a Windows machine.  I have OpenSSL installed.

Here are the steps I am trying:

1. Generate CSR

   ```
   openssl req -out d:\cert\request.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout d:\cert\csrPrivateKey.pem
   ```
2. Upload signed CSR to Apple and download issued certificate (pushCert.pem)
3. Convert .pem certificate to pkcs12

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -in d:\cert\pushCert.pem -inkey d:\cert\csrPrivateKey.pem -out d:\cert\pushCert.p12 -name "apns-cert"
   ```

When I try this last step, I get an error "No certificate matches private key" and an empty file is created.  If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: These commands should work. The error seems to indicate that the public key in `pushCert.pem` doesn't match the private key with which the CSR was generated. Is there more than one certificate (`--BEGIN/.../END--`) in `pushCert.pem` (perhaps you get the chain and your certificate isn't in first position).

Comment: Bruno, I agree completely.. it's driving me crazy!  The pushCert.pem only contains one certificate.  Is it possible I don't have openssl configured correctly, and that is why it is unable to match the private key to the cert?

Comment: Do the public keys shown with `openssl rsa -text -noout -in csrPrivateKey.pem`, `openssl req -text -noout -in request.csr` and `openssl x509 -text -noout -in pushCert.pem` match?

Comment: No. The modulus in request.csr and csrPrivateKey.pem match, but the pushCert.pem I downloaded from Apple is different.  This is definitely the problem, but I am not sure how to fix it or what I did wrong.

Comment: Either you submitted another CSR with different keys or the cert you got is for a different keys (certainly worse if the cert with that different key is issued to your name).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will double check my code!

Comment: Hi Dave and others, I am also got the same issue, let me know the solution